# Which loss function is used in R package gbm for multinomial distribution?

Tags: r, gbm

I am using the R package gbm to fit probabilistic classifiers in a dataset with > 2 classes. I am using `distribution = "multinomial"` as argument, however, I have some difficulties to find out implementation details of what is actually implemented by that choice.

The help function for `gbm` states that

> Currently available options are "gaussian" (squared error), "laplace" (absolute loss), "tdist" (t-distribution loss), "bernoulli" (logistic regression for 0-1 outcomes), "huberized" (huberized hinge loss for 0-1 outcomes), classes), "adaboost" (the AdaBoost exponential loss for 0-1 outcomes), "poisson" (count outcomes), "coxph" (right censored observations), "quantile", or "pairwise" (ranking measure using the LambdaMart algorithm).

and does not list `multinomial`, whereas the paragraph preceding the one I copied states that

> ... If not specified, gbm will try to guess: ...  if  the  response  is  a  factor,multinomial is assumed; ...

I would like to know which loss function is implemented if I specify `distribution = "multinomial"`. The documentation in the vignette which can be accessed via

```
utils::browseVignettes("gbm")
```

does not contain the word "multinomial" or any descriptions of what that argument implies.

I have tried to look at the package source code, but can't find the information there as well. It seems that the relevant things happen in the C++ functions in the file `/src/multinomial.cpp`, however, my knowledge of C++ is too limited to understand what is going on there.

Comment: Are you aware that the authors [discourage](https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm/issues/41#issuecomment-506917696) using it?

Comment: No, I wasn't, thanks for the hint.